# Visual Studio 2010 c++ Sleep()

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010, sleep

I like to use the Sleep() function in a Windows Forms project, but the Sleep() is executed before anything else. I read that i should flush using fflush(), but i don't know what to flush. Can someone help me?

The code:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {                    

             this->label1->Visible= false;
             this->button1->Visible= false;


             r = (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;                              
             r = r*100000;
             i = r;
             r = r - i;              

             String^ strR = "" + r;
             this->label2->Text = strR;


             if(r >= 0.5)
             {
                 this->pictureBox1->Visible= true;
                 this->pictureBox1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Blue;                    
             }
             else
             {
                 this->pictureBox1->Visible= true;
                 this->pictureBox1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Red;                                         
             }   

             Sleep(500);

         }
```

Comment: a question: why are you programming in c++-cli when you would be much safer if writing c#?

Comment: I only know c++ syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call to `Sleep()` is blocking your main (UI) thread, which prevents the message pump from updating your controls.

In this case, it doesn't appear that the call to `Sleep` really serves a purpose, other than blocking your UI - if you want to prevent the button from being pressed again, a better option would be to disable it, then use a timer (`System::Windows::Forms::Timer`) with a 500 ms interval to re-enable the button.

By using a timer, you won't block the UI thread, which allows your controls to stay active, but you still prevent the user from pressing the button.